# Spark UI available on Dataproc Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Looking to interact with the traditional Spark Web GUI on default clusters in Dataproc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by creating a SSH tunnel to the Dataproc master node. By using a SOCKS proxy you can then access all the applications running on YARN including your Spark sessions.

This guide will walk you through in detail:
[Dataproc Cluster web interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/cluster-web-interfaces)