# Install pyspark on Google cloud Dataproc cause "could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching['/tmp', '/usr/local/bin']"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pip, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I create a cluster with Google Cloud Dataproc. I can submit job to the cluster just fine until I do

> pip3 install pyspark

on the cluster. After that, each time I try to submit a job, I received an error:

> Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/tmp',
>   '/usr/local/bin']
>   /usr/local/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /bin/spark-class: No such file or directory

I notice that even before pyspark was installed, SPARK_HOME was not set to anything. However I can submit the job just fine. I wonder why does install pyspark cause this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: if submit job was running successfully then why did you have to install pyspark for? Your manual installation conflicted with the configured pyspark

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yea... I just realized that, I tried to install pyspark because when I run python shell in there and it does not have pyspark module. Right now I am recreating my cluster and see if it will succeed.

Comment: good luck . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248567/spark-ui-available-on-dataproc-cluster should help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark is already pre-installed on Dataproc -- you should invoke the `pyspark` command rather than `python`. For now, trying to pip install pyspark or py4j will break pyspark on Dataproc. You also need to be careful not to pip install any packages that depend on pyspark/py4j. We're aware of this issue :)

If you're just trying to switch to Python 3, currently the easiest way to do that is to run the miniconda initialization action when creating your cluster: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/conda/. That init action conveniently also allows you to specify extra pip or conda packages to install.

We are also aware that `pyspark` isn't on `PYTHONPATH` for the python interpreter. For now, if you want to run pyspark code, use the `pyspark` command. Note that the `pyspark` command sources `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`, which you would have to do manually if you wanted to run `import pyspark` in a `python` shell.

Side note: rather than SSHing into the cluster and running `pyspark`, consider running `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark)) from your workstation or using [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/jupyter).

Answer (score 0):

> brew install apache-spark
>   actually already provides a working pyspark shell. It is not necessary to additionally
>   pip install pyspark